# Fast matrix determinant calculation with specific structure

Tags: r, time-complexity, computation-theory

I have a `k*k` squared matrix with **diagonal elements `x>0`** and **all other elements `y>0`**. The values of `k, x, y` are all subject to change.

Now I need the determinant of this matrix. I know there won't be a closed-form formula for it, but is there a way to calculate it faster than the commonly used LU-decomposition which takes *O(K^3)* time complexity (considering its special structure)?

(I am using `R` as my coding language, and the built-in `det()` function in `R` uses the LU-decomposition.)